# Unable to get Calucaulated Field value from SharePoint Column

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am having SharePoint Calculated column where based on some condition's column is holding Names of Months's (Jan, Feb, March..) and it is **SingleLineText**

Can any one please do help me how can I make it.

Comment: Can please elaborate more

Comment: Can you please share the code you tried?